# A good place for unit test folder: in source code folder, out of it, or ...?

Tags: python, unit-testing

Developing a software project in python, what is the best practice for the location of `tests` folder in a project's structure from production perspective? Is it really matter to place them inside the src folder or outside of it. Does this decision affect the production of the software in any way when everything is made automated?

```
-- my_project
  |---- src
  |---- tests
  |---- ...
```

or

```
-- my_project
  +---- src
      |---- tests
  +---- ...
```

Comment: Your unittests are definitly part of your project's source code.  Where _exactly_ in the source you want to put them depends on your project's size and organization,  eventually which framework (if any) it's based on, and of course your own preferences, but there ARE part of the source code.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to mention one further option to the ones that you have shown, namely to put the unit-tests into a project of their own (one unit-test project for each of the production test projects / components).  What distinguishes these three different options is the degree to which the production code and the test code are separated.

When comparing the different approaches, I see the following criteria:

- Maintaining a clear barrier between production code and test code: Production builds should not contain test code.  For some kinds of software this is not just a recommendation, but a strict requirement (for example in safety critical software) - even if the test code within the production code would be dead code or unreachable.  But, a clear barrier can also be advantageous when designing tests: separation helps to first focus on tests on the public API.  And, sometimes you want to deliver production code to the customer but not the unit-test code or vice-versa (depending on the contract).  This is, obviously, the simpler to achieve the more production code and test code are separated.
- Mutual traceability between production code and related test code: Traceability is easy to achieve when production code and test code are versioned together.  Typical commits to the repository could then contain production code changes and related changes to the tests.  Putting production code and tests into different projects would be a disadvantage here - unless you can somehow ensure that both related projects are consistently versioned, such that it is always clear which versions belong together.  If you would have to ensure this manually, it is likely to fail.

Taking these criteria into account, I would personally say that for many development situations your first solution is the best compromise - given that the language and tool environment allows to fulfill the criteria in an acceptable way.  But, in the end you will have to judge according to your respective development context.

One additional note maybe on integration tests, even if this goes beyond what you have asked: Integration tests do not just belong to one component in one specific version, but to a configuration of two or more components in their specific versions.  Therefore is it for integration tests more plausible to put them into projects of their own.  But, again, there are exceptions here...

Answer (score 2):

This is a matter of opinion you could have the test next to your files, for bigger cohesion, which is a good thing. On the other hand it might "polute" day to day navigation somewhat.

What I'd recommend is to put it at each of units levels.

- law of cohesion: You want your test close enough to your source, but not really pollute the implementation details
- opinionated: usually you don't test internals, only the public api.

```
  src
    cars
      storage
        _car_storage.x
      engine
        _engine.x 
      car.x
      car.test
    motor
      motor.test
      motor.x
```

In this example car_storage and _engine are not part of the public api of car, so those are an implementation detail of the car unit. Therefor no test is required.

If that does not float your boat, I'd recommend putting it next to your src

```
src
tests
```